# $_GET variable not passing while using an htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, get

I am having a bit of trouble with not being able to pass a get variable when I'm using an htaccess file.

I have a rewrite rule that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule user/([0-9]+) user.php?uID=$1&user
```

And I have a small script that looks like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['section'])){ /*DO STUFF HERE*/ } ?> //this doesn't run
```

The problem I'm having is if I go to for example:

```
www.example.com/user/2?section=info
```

the 'section' part of the URL won't get passed in.

Comment: Long story made short: You need a `[QSA]` flag on the `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse the query string in a rewritten URL, you must pass the `[QSA]` (query string append) flag to it, like so:

```
RewriteRule user/([0-9]+) user.php?uID=$1&user [QSA]
```

Comment: Docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa